# Using Images In SWT Browser Component

Tags: eclipse, browser, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

Whats the best way of using images in SWT Browser component. Currently i stream the images to temp folder and use their location for displaying them. Is there any better way of using these images in the SWT Browser component, particulary images from the platform plugins.

Best Regards,
Keshav

Comment: I'm using same way how to display images to user in `Browser` widget. I don't thing, there is a way how to push image to browser from memory directly..

Answer (score 2):

Convert them to a DataURI and insert them into the HTML directly.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Answer (score 1):

If your plug-in is directory-based - rather than jar-based - you can use the files in the plug-in directly. The are several ways to find the file name of an resource entry of a bundle - I prefer `FileLocator.toFileURL(URL)` which converts an URL on the format `platform:/<plugin>/<path>` to a `file:<filename>`... exactly what you need.